# CONSUL DNSMASQ issue

Tags: consul, dnsmasq

I am testing DNS using Consul on RedHat Linux.   I have a problem that when I try to "dig {service name}" it does not work.

I have a local Consul agent running and listening on 8600 for DNS.
I also have configured DNSMASQ to forward the .consul domain dns queries to the local consul agent.

The below works without any problem

dig @x.x.x.x -p 8600 consul.service.consul

dig @x.x.x.x -p 53 consul.service.consul

But when i do ***"dig consul.service.consul"*** it does not work. But this exact query works on my dev machine which is MAC.

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Here is my dnsmasq conf located at /etc/dnsmasq.d/10-consul

server=/consul/x.x.x.x#8600

Answer (score 1):

Was able to fix the issue by adding the below entry onto /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.1